# No longer able to browse for folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, gui, address-bar

I am not sure what happened, but suddenly the dialog for browsing for a folder no longer works on my computer (see screenshot #1 below). It's not just one application. I have at least two more that has the same isue.

Another issue that I believe is related is that some open-file dialog no longer displays the address bar (see screenshot #2). Again, it is several different applications in which this is happening.

I've uninstalled software that was installed right prior to this issue rearing its head, but still nothing. I know I can just go back to a restore point, but I'm curious to know what happened.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Number 1:

[image: Browser for folder]

Number 2:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [someone](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/92412-browse-folder-dialogs-appear-blank.html) solved it by running
[`sfc /scannow`](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)

Comment: Man, I wish I could upvote this asnwer twice.

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting, I would do a system restore before I tried anything else.

Comment: Downvote, really? It was working, now it is not...Go back to when it was working...pretty obvious.

Comment: OK, after rebooting...I was talking about actual troubleshooting.

Comment: I agree. This is by far the best solution, next to googling around for an obscure error that, impossibly, Google hasn't even heard of

Comment: I know that a System Restore is the ultimate answer. I was ju8st curious as to whyy this happened.

Comment: @RHPT I wish I could tell you. I have never seen that before.